# JComboBox not updating after item selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have an error with some code (i'll show it below) where when the user picks an item from the JComboBox, the program doesn't update and thinks that there's no item selected. It's worth mentioning that `.setSelectedIndex` does update and make the program know that the selected item changed, even though it's a result of it being changed by `.setSelectedIndex`
Here's the code: (I'll put all the project's code here as i have no idea what a minimal reproducible example would be in this case, as I don't know what's causing the problem)

```
package sample;

import sun.security.mscapi.CPublicKey;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    static final int WIDTH = 600;
    static final int HEIGHT = 400;
    public static final String TITLE = "Schedule Maker";

    public JButton start;

    //Hour array
    private int[] hours = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,};
    private JTextField heading = new JTextField("Hours");
    private JTextField selectedHour = new JTextField(15);
    private JComboBox hourBox = new JComboBox();

    public Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
            hourBox.addItem(hours[i]);
        }
        hourBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        heading.setEditable(false);
        hourBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                selectedHour.setText("You selected : " + ((JComboBox) event.getSource()).getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        int item = hourBox.getSelectedIndex();

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(heading);
        this.add(selectedHour);
        this.add(hourBox);
    }

    public void create() {

        start = new JButton();

        JFrame frame = new Main();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setTitle("Title (I'm great at names i know)");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("TITLE");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(start);
        start.setText("Select an hour");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ActionListener click = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == start) {
                    if (hourBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                        start.setText("Please select an hour");
                    } else {
                        start.setText("Some text since the rest of the program is not done yet");
                    }
                }
            }

        };

        start.addActionListener(click);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with your code. Let me list them sorted from problematic bugs to, well, style issues ;)

- You are creating **two instances** of your class. The first one in the `main` method, the second one in the `create()` method. The `hourBox` you refer to in `create()` is **not the same object** you display in your `JFrame`! It's all very tangled. This is what causes your problem! Allow me to tidy this up ... the following points are additional issues I see, but they're not related to your problem. I list them anyway to explain the changes I made.
- `JComboBox` is using a generic type, so you should specify it: `JComboBox<Integer> hourBox = new JComboBox<Integer>();`
- There's a lot of unnecessary code, like duplicate calls of `setVisible()`/`setTitle()`/`setSize()`/`setDefaultCloseOperation()` or just unused objects like `panel`.
- You don't need a full array of `int` values to get your hours into the combo box. See the code below!

Trying to apply these thoughts to your code, I come up with this:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8333256750721907342L;
    
    static final int WIDTH = 600;
    static final int HEIGHT = 400;
    
    public static final String TITLE = "Schedule Maker";
    private static final int HOURS = 24;

    
    public Main() {
        
        this.setTitle(TITLE);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        JTextField selectedHour = new JTextField(15);
        JComboBox<Integer> hourBox = new JComboBox<Integer>();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= HOURS; i++) {
            hourBox.addItem(i); // add hour to combo box
        }
        
        hourBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        hourBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                selectedHour.setText(
                        "You selected : " + hourBox.getSelectedItem());
                setTitle("HOUR: " + hourBox.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        //int item = hourBox.getSelectedIndex();

        this.add(new JTextField("Hours"));
        this.add(selectedHour);
        this.add(hourBox);
        
        JButton start = new JButton();
        start.setText("Select an hour");
        this.add(start);
        
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == start) {
                    if (hourBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                        start.setText("Please select an hour");
                    } else {
                        start.setText("gud boi!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center window on screen
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

... it works as expected.

Comment: There should be a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method in your main method to ensure that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @GilbertLeBlanc! My experience with this is limited - you mean I should run the whole GUI initialization on the event dispatch thread like in my edit above?

Comment: Yes, now your main method is correct.  I should have mentioned this before, it's not a good idea to extend a JFrame, or any other Java class, unless you intend to override one or more of the class methods.  Don't change your answer, though.  Just keep it in mind for future coding.

Comment: Actually the list in my answer originally contained an item "_Don't extend `JFrame` unless you actually extend it's functionality_", but I removed it as I figured this issue might be too far off the context of this question. Also, the internet is **full of** code examples where people are extending `JFrame` - and I understand it, as it's very tempting to be able to call the `JFrame`s methods without explicitly referencing another object and see your class as "the class that defines the GUI window". But yeah, sure, it's very wrong semantically from an OOP perspective.

Comment: *Also, the internet is full of code examples where people are extending JFrame...* I know, and it can get annoying continually advising people to quit.  But extending Swing components unnecessarily makes it more difficult to create complex Swing GUIs.